# dot-dash vs dot-prefix in Clojure

Tags: clojure

Why is the dot-dash preferred over dot-prefix when accessing the field of a defrecord in Clojure?

Ex:-

```
(defrecord Person [name age])

(def person1 (Person. "Ak" 28))

(.-name person1)
"Ak"

(.name person1)
"Ak"
```

Comment: For idiomatic clj, `:name` is preferred. `(:name person1)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`.-` is used to signify field access in [Clojure interop](https://clojure.org/reference/java_interop), just `.` is calling a method.

Either way, as mentioned in a comment on the question, using the keyword as in `:name` is the idiomatic way to access the `name` field.

The other methods work because [records](https://clojure.org/reference/datatypes#_deftype_and_defrecord) are built partially to support interop with the host language.

---

Keep in mind that for data modeling in general with Clojure, maps are preferred. [Here's](https://cemerick.com/2011/07/05/flowchart-for-choosing-the-right-clojure-type-definition-form/) a handy flowchart for choosing the right datatype for your situation.